# Can the parameters of the Music Lens be edited?

Tags: unity, music, lenses

I primarily listen to classical music on my laptop. Since I'm obsessed with specifics with my music, I am precise with how I label my genres (Opera, Symphony, Chorale, etc.).

Is there a way to edit the Music Lens so that instead of listing "Blues, Classic, Country..." it could list custom parameters?

Could the same be done for the "Decade" parameter? Maybe make it "Century", since I have music from back in the 1400's :)

Comment: I would love to change the source code for you. Please provide me with all the genres you use. This might be case-sensitive, so please use the exact case.

Comment: Hello there @green7. I know the paramaters of "Decade" options: 1400's, 1500's, 1600's, 1700's, 1800's, 1900's, 2000's, and "Other"--since some don't have recorded dates. As for genres, I have a question: I have genres such as Trumpet concerto, Piano Concerto, Flute Concerto, etc... Would it be possible for the lens to search for a genre containing the word "Concerto" as a possible term?

Comment: Let's see :P I would say that Concerto, Sonata (Piano, Cello, etc), Choral (Cantata, Mass, Requiem), Opera, Symphony, Orchestral (Poem, Suite, Work, etc.), Trio, Quartet. Thank you so much for helping, this would be an amazing option for the lens!

Comment: why dont we try to dynamically populate that list based on what the user has tagged?

Comment: I've created a launchpad issue for this:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-lens-music/+bug/1165308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently these can not be edited, your best bet is to file a feature request with the maintainer.

https://launchpad.net/unity-music-lens

Keep in mind that a lense has to be fed by scopes, so not only does the lense need to be updated but whatever scope is feeding it will need some love too. (default is rhythmbox - I think, I use clementine)